# Não encontra declaração de componente depois de aplicar lazy loading

Tags: angular

Estou tentando aplicar lazy loading na minha aplicação, porém depois que removi a importação do módulo no app.module e deixei apenas no loadChildren, minha aplicação não reconhece uma das minhas declarações de componente.

Meu app Routing Module:

```
//Importação de módulos do angular
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
//Importação de módulos de rotas

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dash', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

Meu Dashboard Routing Module:

```
//Importação de módulos angular
retirado para melhorar visibilidade 

const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
    { path: '', component: BemvindoComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: BemvindoComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'custofixo', component: CustofixoComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'custoextra', component: CustoextraComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'custovariavel', component: CustovariavelComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'listagemcustofixo', component: ListagemCustoFixo, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'operador', component: OperadorComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [CadOperadorGuard]},
    { path: 'produtos', component: ProdutoComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'tipoprodutos', component: TipoprodutoComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'meuperfil', component: MeuperfilComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'confestoque', component: ConfEstoqueComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'confprecificacao', component: ConfPrecificacao, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'monitoramento', component: MonitoramentoComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'listagemcustovariavel', component: ListagemCustoVariavel, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'listagemcustoextra', component: ListagemCustoExtra, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'produtoscalculados', component: ProdutosCalculadosComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class DashboardAppRouting {}
```

Meu deshboard module:

```
//Importação de módulos angular
import { MyMaterialDesignModule } from '../../../app.materialdesign.module';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
//Importação de componentes do módulo
import { DashboardAppRouting } from './dashboard.routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from '../../guards/auth.guard';
import { LoginGuard } from '../../guards/login.guard';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { DialogConfirmacaoExclusao } from '../dialogexclusao/dialog-exclusao.component';
import { ClickOutsideModule } from 'ng4-click-outside';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MyMaterialDesignModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DashboardAppRouting,
    MatMenuModule,
    ClickOutsideModule
  ],
  exports:[
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  declarations: [DashboardComponent,DialogConfirmacaoExclusao],
  providers:[
    AuthGuard,
    LoginGuard,
    ToastrService
  ]
})

export class DashboardModule { }
```

Eu recebo:

> Uncaught Error: Component DialogConfirmacaoExclusao is not part of any
>   NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Answer (score 1):

Existe mais algum componente ou módulo externo ao Dashboard que esteja utilizando o `DialogConfirmacaoExclusao`? Se sim, acredito que coloca-lo no `exports` vai resolver o problema.

```
exports:[
  DashboardComponent, DialogConfirmacaoExclusao
],
```

Comment: Coloquei, mas ainda aparece. Segundo uma video aula que eu vi da loiane depois que eu coloco no approuting, eu devo retirar a importação do meu dashboard module do app.module, mas quando faço isso não encontra a declaração do dialogconfirmacaoexclusao

Comment: Realmente a partir do lazy-loading não é mais necessário incluir no `AppModule`. Esse erro é comum quando um componente que está no lazy-loading está sendo utilizado em outros lugares da aplicação. Você disse estar somente utilizando-o no DashboardModule, certo? Do contrário, seria interessante criar um `SharedModule` (ou `DialogsModule`) que contenha o `DialogConfirmaExclusão` nos `declarations` e `exports`, assim para utilização em todo o sistema importa o `SharedModule` nos módulos que mais desejar, como o `DashboardModule`, por exemplo.

Comment: Mesmo se eu remover o dialogConfirmacaoExclusao, depois começa a alertar que o DashboardComponent não foi declarado em nenhum lugar :(